# Add toolbar in fragment activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently i'm working on google map api . I want to add toolbar/actionbar to   my map fragment.

please check the image in the link below:-

[image: This is the Screen shot please check this out]

this is my layout file .xml

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width`enter code here`="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.android.bhavin04.MapsActivity"
        />
```

my MaintActivity extends FragmentActivity and implements OnMapReadyCallback.
how to add toolbar to my main activity. a help will be appreciated.

main Activity code:

```
package com.android.bhavin04.ganeshutsavmumbai;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private LatLngBounds Mumbai = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(19.075984, 72.877656));


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);




        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Mumbai.getCenter(), 14));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
       // mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        LatLng Mumbai = new LatLng(19.075979, 72.879696);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Mumbai));


     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your activity from `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.
(MainActivity extends `ActionBarActivity`)

`ActionBarActivity` extends from `FragmentActivity` hence it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppCompatActivity` which is extended from `FragmentActivity` and you can design your layout something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.android.bhavin04.MapsActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.android.bhavin04.MapsActivity" />
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above xml code contains `Toolbar` which can be customized anyway you want and can be used as `ActionBar`.